# Id = "root".this.value

Tags: javascript, html, onchange, getelementbyid

I roughly looked for a similar problem but couldn't find a solution.

My problem is, i need to change via a select option menu a `img` and a `href`. That's not a problem if i have to change only one of them ... but the `a href` and the src have different root's and i don't know how i can give them the value which is the same but additional a different root...
Maybe its easier to show the code to get my problem...

```
<select onchange="document.getElementsById('stammimg').src = 'img/stamm/thumb/'.this.value;document.getElementsById('stammref').href = 'img/stamm/'.this.value;">

<option value="img1.png">Stammbaum 1</option>
<option value="img2.png">Stammbaum 2</option>
</select>

<a id="stammref" href=""><img id="stammimg" src="" /> </a> `
```

Well... thats what i have to get to work ... 
As soon as i remove one `getElement` and remove the root before `this.value` the stuff works but like this it doesn't do anything. Any buddy here that could help me here and gets what i need ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `'img/stamm/thumb/'.this.value;` what's this?

Comment: Maybe i misused here something since i thought it may work like in php...
Just wanted to say there that 'img/stamm/thumb/' is the root where the img is the value name of the pics are the same

Comment: JavaScript's string concatenation operator is `+`, not `.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `getElementsById` -> `getElementById`
2. you need to use `+` not `.`
3. Also, do not use an inline event handler.  It is more easy to create a separate function

   ```
   <script>
   var OnChange = function(obj) {  
       document.getElementById('stammimg').src ='img/stamm/thumb/'+obj.value;
       document.getElementById('stammref').href = 'img/stamm/'+obj.value;
   };
   </script>

   <select onchange="OnChange(this)">
       <option value="img1.png">Stammbaum 1</option>
       <option value="img2.png">Stammbaum 2</option>
   </select>

   <a id="stammref" href=""><img id="stammimg" src="" /> </a>
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just coudnt find the right question to find the operator to connect my value with the root... i just kinda thought it's the same as in php ( i barly know the basics ). Could you explain me maybe why you used the `+obj.value` instead of   `this.value` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `+` to concatenate strings in JavaScript rather than the `.` from PHP.

```
<select onchange="document.getElementsById('stammimg').src = 'img/stamm/thumb/' + this.value;document.getElementsById('stammref').href = 'img/stamm/' + this.value;">
```

It would be best to split this code out into a separate function as well:

Add this to your page:

```
<script>
    function selectChanged() {
        document.getElementsById('stammimg').src = 'img/stamm/thumb/' + this.value;
        document.getElementsById('stammref').href = 'img/stamm/' + this.value;
    }
</script>
```

and update the select tag to be:

```
<select onchange="selectChanged">
```